Equivalence of deformed Gaussian Measures
Let $D\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a compact set and $P$ the mean $0$ Gaussian measure on $L^2(D,\mathbb{R}^d)$ with covariance $K$. Let $f_1,f_2:D \mapsto D'$ be diffeomorphisms. Define $P_i$ to be the mean $0$ Gaussian measure on $L^2(D',\mathbb{R})$ with covariance $K_i(x',y') = K(f_i^{-1}(x'), f_i^{-1}(y'))$. Are there simple conditions for the equivalence or singularity of $P_1$ and $P_2$ in terms of $K, f_1$ and $f_2$? I know for example that if $K$ is stationary, and $f_1$ and $f_2$ are just shifts by vectors $v_1$ and $v_2,$ then $P_1$ and $P_2$ are not just equivalent but are one and the same, because $K_1 = K_2$. What about in general, when $K_1 \neq K_2$?
